# Getting the date of next Monday

Tags: javascript, date

How can I get the next Monday in JavaScript? I can't find anything of this in the internet and I have also tried a lot of codes and understanding of this but I can't really do it.

Here's my code:

```
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDay();
d = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + day + (day == 0 ? -6 : 2)));
```

Comment: If today is Monday, then you want next Monday or today's date?

Comment: Check also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481158/how-to-get-the-4-monday-of-a-month-with-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get next date from weekday in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579010/get-next-date-from-weekday-in-javascript)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This will retrieve the next Monday, returning the current date if already a Monday:

```javascript
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + (1 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
console.log(d);
```

To return the following Monday even if the current date is a Monday:

```javascript
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + (((1 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7) || 7));
console.log(d);
```

Comment: that's not working for all cases, for example : "09/26/2017" it gives 32 :) you should test the month and calcule days number in each month

Comment: @MouradIdrissi It gives the correct result for me. `var d = new Date("2017-09-26")`, followed by the code above yields Monday 2 Oct, 2017, which is the next Monday after Tuesday 26 Sep, 2017.

Comment: @VictorZamanian is correct; if you pass 32 as the arg for setDate() into a month with 30 days, you will get the 2nd date of the following month.

Comment: Only the date becomes correct here. The time (hours, minutes, seonds) changes.

Comment: I don't think this works – if today is Monday then this will set the date to today. `d.getDay()` will be 1, `1 + 7 -1` will be 7, `7 % 7` will be 0, so you'll get `setDate(d.getDate() + 0)` – so, not the next Monday, but the same day.

Comment: @Alex which is exactly what it states it would do in the first case, and the reason why the second case has the `|| 7` attached at the end. If the first expression yields 0 as you pointed out, this will be interpreted as falsy, leading to the OR to evaluate and the whole expression to yield 7, which results in the next same weekday as today is.

Answer (score 35):

If the actual day of the week you want is variable (Sunday, Thursday, ...) and you want a choice whether today could be a possible match or not, and it might be that you want to start with another date (instead of today), then this function may be useful:

```js
function getNextDayOfTheWeek(dayName, excludeToday = true, refDate = new Date()) {
    const dayOfWeek = ["sun","mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat"]
                      .indexOf(dayName.slice(0,3).toLowerCase());
    if (dayOfWeek < 0) return;
    refDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    refDate.setDate(refDate.getDate() + +!!excludeToday + 
                    (dayOfWeek + 7 - refDate.getDay() - +!!excludeToday) % 7);
    return refDate;
}

console.log("Next is: " + getNextDayOfTheWeek("Wednesday", false));
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed and wonder why this answer isn't getting more upvote ... is there a way to format the output to DD MM YYYY? @trincot

Comment: @KolawoleEmmanuelIzzy, sure there is. There is  `toLocaleDateString` which has many formatting options. Check out the many questions on the subject.

Comment: @trincot Your solution is very flexible and practical. Personally I would change the boolean addition/subtraction, and that's mostly because TypeScript won't allow it. I would use unary plus to explicitly convert the boolean to 0 or 1.

Comment: Absolutely the best answer

Answer (score 21):

This will give next Monday if today is Monday

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + (7-d.getDay())%7+1);
```

This will result in today if today is Monday

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + ((7-d.getDay())%7+1) % 7);
```

Comment: this works fine in my console, but not in my nodejs code

Comment: works identically for me - if you gave a little more information than *it doesn't work* that'd be just peachy - considering this code gives the same results as the code you accepted, I think you are probably doing it wrong

Comment: I dropped this code in JS fiddle. It worked fine. When I dropped it into my meteor app yesterday, I was getting a date for 14

Answer (score 5):

If you need to handle time zones, one option would be to use the UTCDate methods **setUTCDate()** and **getUTCDate()**.  This allows for consistency so the calculation is the same no matter the time zone setting.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + (7 - d.getUTCDay()) % 7 + 1);
```

(This is the example from above where on a Monday the following Monday is returned)

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution

```js
var days =[1,7,6,5,4,3,2];
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()+days[d.getDay()]);
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var closestMonday = () => {
    var curr_date = new Date(); // current date
    var day_info = 8.64e+7; // milliseconds per day
    var days_to_monday = 8 - curr_date.getDay(); // days left to closest Monday
    var monday_in_sec = curr_date.getTime() + days_to_monday * day_info; // aleary Monday in seconds from 1970 
    var next_monday = new Date(monday_in_sec); // Monday in date object
    next_monday.setHours(0,0,0);
    return next_monday;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Other responses seems not to take into account that "next Monday" should be at the beginning of the day. Here's how I've implemented it recently:

```js
function getNextMonday() {
  const now = new Date()
  const today = new Date(now)
  today.setMilliseconds(0)
  today.setSeconds(0)
  today.setMinutes(0)
  today.setHours(0)

  const nextMonday = new Date(today)

  do {
    nextMonday.setDate(nextMonday.getDate() + 1) // Adding 1 day
  } while (nextMonday.getDay() !== 1)

  return nextMonday
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or more simple:

```
let now = new Date();
let day = 1; // Monday

if (day > 6 || day < 0) 
  day = 0;
    
while (now.getDay() != day) {
  now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
}
now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);

console.log(now); // next Monday occurrence
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to find the offset (in number of days) to the day you want, turn that into milliseconds, and add it to you starting date:

```
let d = new Date();
const day = d.getDay();
const targetDay = 1;  // Monday
let dayOffset = targetDay - day;
if (dayOffset < 0) dayOffset += 7;

d = new Date(d.getTime() + (dayOffset * 24 * 3600 * 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
d = new Date(d);
var day = d.getDay(),
diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1);
alert(new Date(d.setDate(diff)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/),

```
moment().add(7, 'days').calendar();
```

Comment: The question was not > Which library / Framework can i use ? <

Comment: Is it mentioned anywhere in the original question? The person was looking for a solution and I gave mine using a popular library.

Comment: But also, this simply adds 7 days to the current day, it doesn't get you the next Monday on any arbitrary day that the code is run on..

Answer (score 0):

I see many answers and trust me, I've done some digging.

In the case you want to get next Monday - 00:00:00 - regardless of time zone try the following snippet.
It works with input ranging from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.

```js
function getNextMonday(d) {
    let date = new Date(new Date(d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + (7 - d.getUTCDay()) % 7 + 1)).setUTCHours(0,0,0));
    let nextMonday = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), 0, 0, 0)).toISOString();
    
    return nextMonday;
}

console.log(getNextMonday(new Date("2023-12-03T00:00:00.000+0000")));
console.log(getNextMonday(new Date("2023-12-03T23:59:59.000+0000")));
console.log(getNextMonday(new Date()));
```

Hope I could be of service :)