# See what day of the week a specicifc date is

Tags: javascript, html, api, date

I am working on a web application, where one of the functionalities is to provide billboard listings based on a date that you insert.

I found this great unofficial API for Billboard charts:
http://billboard.modulo.site/

As you can see in the documentation you can provide a date for the REQUEST and get the official "hot 100" listings for that date.

However, one constraint with this is that **the date provided has to be a saturday**(that's when Billboard updates their charts each week). If you input a date that is not a saturday the response is a json with empty arrays.

If I present the user with the option to select the year, month, and date(or week, doesn't matter) what would be the most efficient solution in **Javascript** to convert that to the date of the saturday on the same week?

For instance let's say the user inputs the following date:
2016-03-04 (which is a Friday)

How could I check what day of the week 2016-03-04 is - so that I could change that to **2016-03-05(which is the saturday)?**

It would be even more pleasant if the user input would be

- Year: 2016
- Month: March
- Week: 9

and then get the date of the saturday of week 9 but not sure if that's possible.

The simplest solutions seems to just see which day of the week a provided date is, but not sure how one could go through with that.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to get the date of the **next Saturday** for a given date.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + (1 + 5 - date.getDay()) % 7);
console.log(date);
```

[Inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078406/getting-the-date-of-next-monday)

Comment: Thanks! Pretty clever using modulus

Answer (score 1):

I would guide the user by providing a date picker and ensuring that only Saturdays can be selected.

The [jQuery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) can be used, for example, and restricted this way. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501943/can-the-jquery-ui-datepicker-be-made-to-disable-saturdays-and-sundays-and-holid) for a way to do this.

This is good from a user perspective and makes your job easier in terms of not having to calculate the 'nearest Saturday'.

It is pretty easy to do. Here's a working sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onlySaturdays(date) {
            return [!!(date.getDay() === 6)];
        }
        $( function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ beforeShowDay: onlySaturdays });
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's quite an elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:
JavaScript:

```
var dateString = document.getElementById('input');
var d = new Date(dateString);
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDate()];
if n = "Saturday" {
//code here
}
else {
//code here for switching
}
```