# Send message in given time (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to do something in X hours/days. So for example, i would like to send a message on every Monday 8:00 AM. I don't trust my hosting, my BOT is restarting much times. What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your bot is running a little bit before those times, you can set

```js
function sendMessage(){
    // ...
}
bot.on('ready', ()=>{
    // ...
    let now = new Date();
    let target = new Date()
    target.setDate(now.getDate() + ((7-now.getDay())%7+1)); // next Monday
    target.setHours(8); // eight o'clock
    target.setMinutes(0); target.setSeconds(0); target.setMilliseconds(0);
    setTimeout(sendMessage, target.now() - now.now());
});
```

You may want to double check some of the date-checking time, and the next Monday bit is from [Getting the date of next Monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078406/getting-the-date-of-next-monday).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) to do that.

Or you can create your own scheduler to archive this purpose.
Create some schedule struct like this in your database:

```
{
  "nextRun": "2017-01-02T12:00:00Z",
  "payload": { /* something for the job */ },
}
```

In your scheduler, set interval to frequently check for schedule from your database. If the `nextRun` matched the current time, execute the job, then calculate and update the `nextRun`.