# Finding the dates of next week in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate the dates of next week in a concise and efficient manner. So far, I am able to calculate next monday correctly and convert it to the required mm/dd/yyyy format. However, how could i do this for the entire week, while taking in to account month endings? I am concerned adding one to the date calculated 7 times will cause some silly errors in the future. Thanks.

Here is my code so far:

```js
const getNextWeekDates = () => {
      const nextMonday = new Date();
      
      nextMonday.setDate(
        nextMonday.getDate() + ((1 + 7 - nextMonday.getDay()) % 7)
      );
      
    
      let dd = nextMonday.getDate();
      
      let mm = nextMonday.getMonth() + 1;
      
      const yyyy = nextMonday.getFullYear();
      
    
      if (dd < 10) dd = `0${dd}`;
      if (mm < 10) mm = `0${mm}`;
    
      return {
        monday: `${mm}/${dd}/${yyyy}`,
        tuesday: '',
        wednesday: '',
        thursday: '',
        friday: '',
        saturday: '',
        sunday: ''
      };
    };
    
    console.log(getNextWeekDates())
```

Comment: I would just use a date library like moment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078406/getting-the-date-of-next-monday

Comment: On monday your function delivers the same day and not the monday next week, is this desired? Test it with `const nextMonday = new Date('2020-08-03');`, you will get `monday: "08/03/2020",`.

Comment: Looks like you have the right idea to start. I suggest using a loop to calculate the rest of the dates.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date#563442