# Get All Monday Dates In Month using Moment,js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Is there any way to get all the Monday DATES in the current month using moment.js library.

I know I can get the end of the month with:

```
moment().endOf('month')
```

but how to get all monday dates of current / any month.

I dont want some function in javascript default date library. Please refer the code using Moment Js Library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the 4 monday of a month with js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481158/how-to-get-the-4-monday-of-a-month-with-js)

Comment: @JotaBe Please refer the code using Moment Js Library. I dont want to parse javascript default date library

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've just read docs and haven't found any method that returns an array, so you need to do it only with loop

```
var monday = moment()
    .startOf('month')
    .day("Monday");
if (monday.date() > 7) monday.add(7,'d');
var month = monday.month();
while(month === monday.month()){
    document.body.innerHTML += "<p>"+monday.toString()+"</p>";
    monday.add(7,'d');
}
```

[check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/Luetpgfe/138/)

Comment: Edited your answer so it works for all months.  The problem is, `.day("Monday")` can actually move backwards into the prior month, depending on how the month boundary falls within the week, so you have to test for that.  Then, `.add(7,'d')` is cleaner, as then the day of week can be changed in one place if desired.

Answer (score 9):

**Update**

I made a little [drop in](https://gist.github.com/penne12/ae44799b7e94ce08753a/) for this. Add it to your page:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/penne12/ae44799b7e94ce08753a/raw/moment-daysoftheweek-plus.js"></script>
```

And then:

```
moment().allDays(1) //=> [...]
moment().firstDay(1)
```

etc - feel free to check out the [source](https://gist.github.com/penne12/ae44799b7e94ce08753a/)

**Old Post**

This function should work:

```
function getMondays(date) {
    var d = date || new Date(),
        month = d.getMonth(),
        mondays = [];

    d.setDate(1);

    // Get the first Monday in the month
    while (d.getDay() !== 1) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    }

    // Get all the other Mondays in the month
    while (d.getMonth() === month) {
        mondays.push(new Date(d.getTime()));
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
    }

    return mondays;
}
```

Usage: `getMondays()` for this month, or `getMondays(moment().month("Feb").toDate())` for a different month.

From [jabclab's Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481478/3144928), modified to include custom date param.

Comment: Thanks for the drop in. There are a couple of bugs with the methods though so could you turn on the issues list or allow a PR?

Comment: @webnoob - it's a gist - so it doesn't accept prs. Feel free to fork the gist and change it, and I'll revise the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old but this is the first thing that comes up in Google.

You can get all the Mondays in the month by using my [moment-weekdaysin](https://github.com/kodie/moment-weekdaysin) moment.js plugin:

```
moment().weekdaysInMonth('Monday');
```

Comment: Thanks for this plugin. It is really simple and well working.