# MomentJS - selecting weekdays

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a calendar in which you can select dates. For now if I wanted to select Mondays from one date to another I had to click every single Monday. This is what I wrote to be able to select mutliple dates with specific weekday:

```
    // selectedDates variable consists already selected dates in form of MomentJS objects
    let result = [...selectedDates];

    // Supplying a dateFrom and dateTo
    const dateFrom = moment().add(-1, "year");
    const dateTo = moment();
    console.log(`Range from ${dateFrom.format("DD-MM-YYYY")} to ${dateTo.format("DD-MM-YYYY")}`)

    const dates = [];
    const indexes = []; // Indexes of common dates

    // Enumerating to get dates that weekday is equal to supplied weekday (not included here)
    // Also checking if those dates are already in the selectedDates array and if true then saving their indexes to an array
    while(dateFrom.add(1, "days").diff(dateTo) < 0) {
        if (dateFrom.format("dd") === weekday) {
            dates.push(dateFrom.clone());
            const index = selectedDates.findIndex(date => date.isSame(dateFrom, "day"));
            if (index > -1) { indexes.push(index); }
        }
    }

    // If there are already less dates in the selectedDates array then I want to select what's left
    // Else just deselect all dates
    if (dates.length > indexes.length) {
        const difference = _.differenceWith(dates, selectedDates, (a, b) => a.isSame(b, "day"));
        result.push(...difference);
    } else {
        result = _.differenceWith(selectedDates, dates, (a, b) => a.isSame(b, "day"));
    }

    return result;
```

The code is working as expected, but if I have a range of (let's say) 1 year, the latency is about 0.5s if selecting every single weekday (364 dates)

My question is if there is a room for improvement in the performance of this code? I'm sure there is, but I can't really find it.

Comment: I think that could help to You: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620161/get-all-monday-dates-in-month-using-moment-js

Comment: or this one is a ready code, and I think also faster than yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194368/how-to-get-all-sundays-mondays-tuesdays-between-two-dates

Comment: @peter I already have all the selected weekday between 2 dates. It's the first `while` loop, and it's fast. I wanted to know if there is some other solution for the code that appears after the while loop - searching through already selectedDates etc.