# Firefox: javascript while loop running too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, while-loop, timeout

I was looking into getting all mondays in a month, in order to create a full list of weeks between two predefined dates and I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481158/how-to-get-the-4-monday-of-a-month-with-js?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) on stackoverflow.
It works like charm on chrome but not on firefox: takes too long and breaks.
Debugging the code it turns out this bit of code takes a lot of time to execute:

```
// Get the first Monday in the month
while (d.getDay() != 1) {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}
```

I usually run my apps on chrome but I want the users to be able to run it on firefox if they prefer. So is there a way to do this without it breaking?

Comment: What exactly is `d`? The current date?

Comment: in the link above we have `var d = newDate()`

Comment: I don't follow links, please add all the relevant information to the question itself.

Comment: It seems  to take about 0.55 msecs to execute the given task (includes new date and console.log too) in FF, that's "_a lot of time_"?

Comment: works like a charm in my FF. maybe that problem is bound to your machine?