# How to get how many weeks and days in a month in Javascript and logic formulation

Tags: javascript, logic, bootstrap-daterangepicker

So I have this `daterangepicker` In which by default the date is 2020/04/15 and besides it is the `<select>` element that has choices of "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly" (Please see picture below).

[image]

Is there any way to compute for which day a week starts in april and how many days april have whenever I clicked the weekly or the monthly in the dropdown besides the `daterangepicker`.

For example:

April has 30 days and week 1 starts at April 6
while in March it has 31 days and week 1 starts at March 2

I know that every month has 4 weeks in it but the question is how can i get the day that starts the week in every month. Is there any way to calculate it in javascript? Or should i just start with day 1 then just count 7 days?

Comment: so you want to get the first monday of month. There was already a solution .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481158/how-can-i-get-the-4-mondays-of-a-month-with-js . You can basically apply the same idea to other date of month.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and pick a datetime library that answers that question (date.js, moment.js, ... there are some out there, I just don't know which one has a function fit for your purpose). No matter what calendar/datetime question you have: ask a library. Instead of an argument from me to support that claim, listen to Tom Scott in this (timeless) rant on time and time zones: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a basic one...

```js
// prepare select for demo
for(let i=2015; i<2026;i++) eYear.add( new Option(i, i) )
eYear.value = 2020

function calcMonthInfos( month=0, year=2020 ) // default on January 2020
  {
  let nDay = 0, lastDay = 28, wDay, wMonth
    ; 
  do { wDay = new Date(year,month,++nDay).getDay() }
  while (wDay != 1)  // sunday is day 0 , monday day 1
    ;
  do { wMonth = new Date(year,month,++lastDay).getMonth() }
  while (wMonth == month)  //  check month changing
    ;
  return ({ monday1fst: nDay, monthDays:--lastDay })
  }  


// démo code :
btGetInfo.onclick=_=>
  {
  let monthInfo = calcMonthInfos(parseInt(eMonth.value), parseInt(eYear.value) )
    , MonthName = eMonth.options[eMonth.selectedIndex].text
    ;
  info.textContent = `First monday of ${MonthName} ${eYear.value} ` 
                   + `is the ${monthInfo.monday1fst}, ` 
                   + `this month has ${monthInfo.monthDays} days`
  }
```

```html
<select id="eMonth">
  <option value="0"> January </option>
  <option value="1"> February</option>
  <option value="2"> March</option>
  <option value="3"> April</option>
  <option value="4"> May</option>
  <option value="5"> June</option>
  <option value="6"> July</option>
  <option value="7"> August</option>
  <option value="8"> September</option>
  <option value="9"> October</option>
  <option value="10"> November</option>
  <option value="11"> December</option>
  </select>

<select id="eYear"></select>

<br><br>
 
<button id="btGetInfo">get info</button>

<p id="info">...</p>
```

Comment: But how can i use it on my daterangepicker?

Comment: @ElijahLeis ... well, I changed my code to make it a function **calcMonthInfos** (at the start you just asked which method to follow)

Comment: Sorry. But your code works! Thanks for that :) I'll try to integrate it with my daterangepicker.